# Is it possible to echo message form config.xml?

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, javascript

I am trying to echo a message from my config.xml in an alert javascript.

Is this possible with magento?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: Please define "message" in config.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your config file:

```
<default>
  <myzone>
    <myspace>               
        <name>myname</name>                                 
    </myspace>    
  </myzone>
</default>
```

You can access your config variables with the following code:

```
echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('myzone/myspace')->name;
```